# Can't save to wav from python, can't import SpeechLib from comtypes.gen, what next?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, sapi

First the setup: Windows 8.1 64bit, Python 3.4 32bit.

I wanted to run the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16590979/2883238). So I installed comtypes

```
pip install comtypes
```

I then tried to run the code, i got

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib'
```

Then tried this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900683/2883238) to try and generate the needed SpeechLib module.

I am however still getting the same error, what should I try next?

Answer (score 3):

Running these lines made it work:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
engine = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
stream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
```

Output was:

```
# Generating comtypes.gen._C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4
# Generating comtypes.gen.SpeechLib
```

After this I got no import error anymore, as expected.